# Richtext area field (with Image) in VF page to be rendered as Doc file

Tags: apex, visualforce, html, richtextarea, renderas

I have a richtext area on Account object. This field as some text and an image etc. This is my simple visuaforce page to get the page as a doc.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" contentType="application/msword#filename.doc" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" showHeader="false"> 
 <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Arichtext__c}"/>
</apex:page>
```

When I save it, a doc file gets downloaded with no image and only text:
[image]

However when I use only `renderAs="pdf"` in my VF page. I get the image as well as the text:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" renderas="pdf" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" showHeader="false">
 <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Arichtext__c}"/>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

On reading further online it seems like Rich text image cannot come in doc type.

1. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000098wOIAQ
2. [Images are not displaying in MS Word Doc](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63713/images-are-not-displaying-in-ms-word-doc)

Is there really a solution available to have this image come in the word document? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In rich text the image is stored in different server (content.force.com) you can check it using inspect element did you tried

```
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!Account.Arichtext__c}"/>
```

it will work if you save it as HTML saving as doc will not work as images hosted on the different server. In the case of PDF Salesforce is taking the responsibility of rendering the image.

Comment: Did you mean the image can be only viewed if saved as .html instead of .docx?

Comment: What I mean it is not possible to show an image in the MS word. it will be blank in my example you can see the raw HTML and in that HTML the image url is secure one which mean it need valid session id. so the only way to put the image on document folder to show it on a MS word from rich text it is not possible

Comment: see this https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000098wOIAQ and https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000096NMIAY